# Can I include PayPal with SSLCOMMERZ in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I am trying to build an online store with WordPress. I can use sslcommerz easily. The problem is I don't know, how to intigrate sslcommerz with PayPal. If there is have any way to do this, please suggest to me how to do it. It will be really helpful for me. If there is no way to do this, feel free to say that. I will happily accept it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the online store in WP, I suggest use Woocommerce, you can easily configure the payment PayPal and stripe.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My store is mainly for Bangladesh and trying to add a facility for other countries clients. I have already used Woocommerce. Thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: That seems very confusing sslcommerz seems already like a payment gateway, How do you want in to integrate it with Paypal ?? sslcommerz seems to have a plugin with woocommerce which I belive should work fine if they accept international payments. See : https://github.com/sslcommerz/SSLCommerz-Woocommerce

Comment: For International customers.

Answer (score 0):

SSLCommerz supports collecting money from international customers through credit/debit card payment but not paypal (due to regulatory obligations).

In that case, the amount will be converted to Bangladesh Taka using daily exchange rate and the converted currency(BDT) will be deposited in your merchant account.

[disclaimer: I work in SSLCommerz.]